# Why does this JPanel delete all items after the first view?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

```
package repository;

import db_operation_package.ComboBoxOperations;
import db_operation_package.ConnectionDB;

public class ModificaPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    ConnectionDB ConnectionDBDriver;

    public ModificaPanel(ConnectionDB conn) {
        this.ConnectionDBDriver = conn;
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private void initComponents() {
        .    //NetBeans generated code
        .
        .
    }                      

    private void elementiModComboBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
        switch (String.valueOf(elementiModComboBox.getSelectedItem())) {
            case "Progetto":
                dadIntModPanel.removeAll();
                dadIntModPanel.add(packModPanel);
                dadIntModPanel.repaint();
                dadIntModPanel.revalidate();
                new ComboBoxOperations().fillComboBox(packageModComboBox, "NOME_PACK, ID_PACK", "PACKAGE", "", ConnectionDBDriver);
                break;
            default:
                dadIntModPanel.removeAll();
                dadIntModPanel.repaint();
                dadIntModPanel.revalidate();
                break;
        }
    }                                                   


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel dadIntModPanel;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> elementiModComboBox;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel packModPanel;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> packageModComboBox;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

elementiModComboBoxActionPerformed displays the elements of packModPanel the first time, but if I change the value in the elementiModComboBox (the switch is in the default case) and I try to return in packModPanel all the elements have disappeared. Why does it happen?

```
public void fillComboBox(JComboBox comboBoxElement, String selectName, String fromTable, String whereString, ConnectionDB connectionDriver){
        comboBoxElement.removeAllItems();
        comboBoxElement.addItem("Nessuno");
        ResultSet resultForComboBox = connectionDriver.selectDistinctQuery(selectName, fromTable, whereString);
        String comboBoxElementString = null;
        try{
            ResultSetMetaData metadata = resultForComboBox.getMetaData();
            int columnCount = metadata.getColumnCount();
            while(resultForComboBox.next()){
                for (int indexColumn = 1; indexColumn <= columnCount; indexColumn++) {
                    if(indexColumn == 1){
                        comboBoxElementString = resultForComboBox.getString(1);
                    }
                    else{
                        comboBoxElementString += ",";

                    comboBoxElementString += resultForComboBox.getString(indexColumn);
                    }
                }
                comboBoxElement.addItem(comboBoxElementString);
                comboBoxElementString = null;
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Errore: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Errore: " + e.getMessage());

        }
    }
```

This is the method that fills the combobox with a sql query, works in other parts of code.

Comment: 1) why do you keep creating a new instance of `ComboBoxOperations`. Your panel should just have a "reset" method that you invoke. 2) The order should be revalidate() and then repaint(). The revalidate() invokes the layout manager to give the components a size/location. The repaint() will then paint the components. 3) if the "default" logic is executing then you need to debug your code to determine why.

Comment: I'm sorry, my fault. The switch case always enters the default condition because "Progetto" is not an element of the combobox. Thanks for the answer anyway!